# Attach Flyout to Listview

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have a Listview defined like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvPlaylist" Width="530" Height="337" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="gvPlaylist_ItemClick">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding albumArtURI}"  Height="48" Width="48" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding GetPlaylistFormat}" Width="500" Height="18"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I want to open a "context"-Flyout on each Item on click.
So far I was only able to attach the flyout to the whole but then the flyout is shown at the border of the listview - not directly attached to the selected item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Button`s have a `Flyout` property. All you have to do is wrap the contents of the template in a `Button`, create a `Style` for the button which removes all visuals for it, then create a `Flyout` for it.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonWrapperStyle}">
        <Button.Content>
            <Grid>
                <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding albumArtURI}"  Height="48" Width="48" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding GetPlaylistFormat}" Width="500" Height="18"/>
            </Grid>
        </Button.Content>
        <Button.Flyout>
        <!-- Make Flyout Here -->
        </Button.Flyout>
    </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

Obviously there is stuff left to do here, but you get the idea.

Hope this helps and happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can also do it like this

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/bg182878.aspx#Flyout)

"The next example shows a Flyout attached to a TextBlock. As noted earlier, you can attach a Flyout to any FrameworkElement by using the FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout attached property."

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MyTextBox, Path=Text}"
           Tapped="TextBlock_Tapped" FontSize="18">
    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <Flyout>
            <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" Text="You can edit this text by tapping it."/>
        </Flyout>
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: The MSDN link is broken, but the code still works.  You have to set "IsTapEnabled" and open the flyout in the "Tapped" event `FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(sender as FrameworkElement);`